# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - July 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 22nd edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for July 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              500
2   nohillside                270
3   bmike, Monomeeth          220
4   grg                       160
5   Tetsujin, Steve Chambers  130
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,675 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-07-01).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              219
2   nohillside                 99
3   bmike                      92
4   ankii                      49
5   IconDaemon                 44
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 807
2   PeterJ                    570
3   bmike                     257
4   ankii                     254
5   Nimesh Neema              158
```

A big thank you to all 58 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 86
2   Nimesh Neema               41
3   Steve Chambers             17
4   fsb, Monomeeth             15
5   bmike                      13
```

A big thank you to all 12 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              204
2   Monomeeth                 134
3   ankii                     126
4   fsb                       101
5   Greenonline, grg           51
```

A big thank you to all 24 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Tetsujin                   44
2   ankii                      31
3   Nimesh Neema               28
4   grg                        21
5   fsb                        17
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               21
2   Glorfindel                 10
3   Steve Chambers, nohillside  9
4   Tetsujin                    8
5   fsb                         5
```

A big thank you to all 12 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 25
2   Tetsujin, Nimesh Neema     12
3   Steve Chambers, bmike, 
    grg, Monomeeth              4
4   fsb                         3
5   Glorfindel                  2
```

A big thank you to all 11 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 68
2   Nimesh Neema               46
3   bmike                      22
4   grg, Glorfindel            17
5   fsb, Steve Chambers        16
```

A big thank you to all 43 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [How do you move up one folder in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364020/how-do-you-move-up-one-folder-in-finder)

   - Posted by: YungGun
   - Votes: **28**
2. [How can I find what program is preventing my Mac from going to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364622/how-can-i-find-what-program-is-preventing-my-mac-from-going-to-sleep)

   - Posted by: TorBro
   - Votes: **13**
3. [Can I activate an iPhone without an Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364468/can-i-activate-an-iphone-without-an-apple-id)

   - Posted by: Serban
   - Votes: **13**
4. [Why isn't a binary file shown as 0s and 1s?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364789/why-isnt-a-binary-file-shown-as-0s-and-1s)

   - Posted by: 244boy
   - Votes: **10**
5. [How to md5 a list of filepaths contained in a file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364196/how-to-md5-a-list-of-filepaths-contained-in-a-file)

   - Posted by: Erics
   - Votes: **10**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [How do you move up one folder in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364032/168832)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **53**
2. [Why isn't a binary file shown as 0s and 1s?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364790/168832)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **28**
3. [How do you move up one folder in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364027/168832)

   - Posted by: Steve Chambers
   - Votes: **20**
4. [How can I find what program is preventing my Mac from going to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364623/168832)

   - Posted by: Monomeeth
   - Votes: **19**
5. [Can I activate an iPhone without an Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364483/168832)

   - Posted by: Stack Overflown
   - Votes: **15**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Why isn't a binary file shown as 0s and 1s?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364789/why-isnt-a-binary-file-shown-as-0s-and-1s)

   - Posted by: 244boy
   - Votes: **5,165**
2. [Can't enlarge photos in google images Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365356/cant-enlarge-photos-in-google-images-safari)

   - Posted by: Mikmak9068
   - Views: **5,000**
3. [How do you move up one folder in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364020/how-do-you-move-up-one-folder-in-finder)

   - Posted by: YungGun
   - Views: **3,732**
4. [Can I activate an iPhone without an Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364468/can-i-activate-an-iphone-without-an-apple-id)

   - Posted by: Serban
   - Votes: **2,120**
5. [Accidentally deleted everything from a directory on my Macbook using terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365688/accidentally-deleted-everything-from-a-directory-on-my-macbook-using-terminal)

   - Posted by: Iamanon
   - Votes: **1,633**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [YungGun](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/338017/yunggun)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [244boy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/257072/244boy)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In July our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **226 flags** with an average handling time of **29 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 344 comments
- deleted 110 posts
- closed 222 posts
- edited 372 posts
- created 120 posts
- created 644 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>